# Rewrite (translate) paged part of a URL in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I would like to translate the paged part of a URL, like so:
currently: mysite.com/page/2
I would like: mysite.com/p/2

Does anybody know of a filter to do this?
Or would a custom rewrite be more appropriate? If yes, how?

Thanks,
Regards.

Comment: It looks like you're talking about your "permalink" structure. In that case, are you specifically talking about WordPress "Pages" (as opposed to "Posts"), or the URLs to blog posts themselves?

Comment: URLs to blog posts. When you paginate the post.

Answer (score 2):

OK add this below code in your theme function.php file

and reset you permalink

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_page_word' );
function my_custom_page_word() {
global $wp_rewrite;
$wp_rewrite->pagination_base = "p";
}
```

Thank you
Manzurul

Answer (score 0):

You need an action, not a filter.

This function will work directly with your translation package, formatting your new base  and prevent to run more than once the flush_rewrite_rules function avoiding bad performance of your blog.

```
function my_change_rewrite_base() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $bases = array(
        'author' => __('Author'), 
        'search' => __('Search'), 
        'comments' => __('Comments)', 
        'pagination' => __('Page')
    );

    foreach ($bases AS $key => $base) {
        $wp_rewrite->{$key} = remove_accents(mb_strtolower($base));
    }

    if ( ! get_option('my_change_rewrite_base_flushed', false) ) {
        flush_rewrite_rules();
        update_option( 'my_change_rewrite_base_flushed', time());
    }
}
add_action('init', 'my_change_rewrite_base');
```